# How can I make an array of all lists length x of the numbers 0 and 1?

Tags: php

I need to create an array like this:

```
$array = array(array(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1), array(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0));
```

but with all combinations of 1 and 0.

I wish to do this automatically, so I was thinking a for loop would be the best idea. 
In other words the inner arrays should be all combos like 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 then 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 then 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 then 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1. for all combos.
I started like this:

```
$array = array();
for($i =0;$i<100; $i++){
$array[$i] = 0;
}
```

How do I get this to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: It looks exactly like a list of binary numbers... did you notice that?

Comment: yess i actually did, but not sure how to get all binary numbers

Answer (score 2):

Use [`decbin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) to convert your counter to binary.

[`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) allows you to pad strings, in this case I'm 0-padding it to a length of 8 bits.

```
$array = array();
for($i =0;$i<100; $i++){
    $array[$i] = str_pad(decbin($i), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);;
}
var_dump($array);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/Z6aqKGKY)

Answer (score 1):

This will print out an array of all binary variations from `00000000` to `11111111` where each one is in it's own array of chars.

```
$array = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 256;)
{
    $array[] = str_split(sprintf('%08d', decbin($i++)));
}
print_r($array);
```

See **[example](http://viper-7.com/IFLNE1)**

Comment: +1 for this one - I think an "array of arrays" is what the OP asked for. Really like the compact use of `decbin`, `sprintf("%08d"`, and `str_split` - masterful!